# jQuery datatables disable row highlight without changing css

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I know I can change the CSS or override the CSS with another bit of styling elsewhere. However I have many of tables that rely on datatables and its highlighting for presentation needs. Except this one table I have, this one table I do not want it, nor do the people who pay me.. so. Im thumbing through the docs and I can't seem to find any direct method, and everyone else just suggests changing it up via CSS.

Im hoping here someone knows of some buried in the docs, function of turnning of the highlight that Im not seeing?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Can you provide an example of what is happening? How is the highlight being accomplished?

Comment: by default I would assume? with the row/column highlighting that comes stock with datatables.

Comment: So you're saying the database software (such as SQL Server Management Studio) lets you highlight rows by clicking on them, and you want to be able to do this with the rows you display on a webpage?

Can you provide an example of the source code you're currently using to display the tables - such as what gets generated after the data is returned from the database?

Comment: no, im saying I am using datatables (www.datatables.net) and for some reason or another.. this instance where columns/rows get highlighted when hovering over the row.. is occurring, and I'd like to sort out how to disable that. Cause I believe it to be a stock part of datatables, but could be wrong? Either way though I don't think I mentioned anything about a database anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you meant a database table since I had no indication that datatables was a plug-in and wasn't familiar with it.

Have you looked at the examples for [Row highlighting with CSS](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/highlight.html) and how to [Highlight rows and columns](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/highlight.html)? Presumably if you want to disable highlighting you either need to not implement those or to implement them in a way that they don't affect the table you wish to exclude.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? This is probably what forces row highlighting, and not DataTables.